# Run Commands without Spaces

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I won't bore you with the details but I need to pass a command to a file without spaces, with each space it considers the next text to be a variable which is not the case. I need to be able to create a command with another character other than space or use hex characters to overcome this. Unfortunately I am completely locked to using this method as this file exists on 1000s of devices and I would need to change the file manually on each device, if I can workaround it's limitations then this would be the best solution for me.

Does anyone have any ideas if this is possible?

**edit**
Hi guys for some more info, lets say I have the file test.sh, it has a function called echo_var, if I use the command for example

```
test.sh echo_var helloworld
```

The function will simply echo helloworld

If I say use the command

```
test.sh echo_var hello world
```

Only hello gets echoed as it considers "hello world" as two strings and only acknowledges the first one, the function takes each separated string as a variable and only uses the first variable ie hello. I need to make hello world one variable

The command I want to run is to restart a service ie

```
test.sh echo_var hello&&service apache2 restart
```

So both hello will be echoed and the service restarted. But after the space after service, the command is cut.

Here is the file (test.sh) I have to interact with, again this is on 1000s of devices and I need to work with it:

```
case "$1" in
    echo_var)
        echo "$2"
        ;;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. What does "pass a command to a file mean"? Give us detailed examples how the files look, what you want to do etc.

Comment: @Sven I have added an edit that will hopefully clear things up

Comment: Did you try to "quote" your hello world string?  Kind of need to see the real example of your script to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: The command I want to run is to restart a service ie test.sh echo_var hello&&service apache2 restart. So both hello will be echoed and the service restarted. But after the space after service, the command is cut.

Answer (score 3):

Use double quote around your string

Below one should work fine

```
test.sh echo_var "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo_var="hello world"
echo  $echo_var
```

Are you looking for something like this?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo_var="Apache Server Restarted"
echo  $echo_var >> /var/log/ApacheRestart.log
service apache2 restart
```

So something like this might help you out.

Comment: I have put the bash file function I am trying to interact with

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254425/using-variable-as-case-pattern-in-bash

Comment: I didn't write the sh file, it came on a device I am using. There are 1000s of these devices in use all with the same file. I am trying to interact with the existing file but pass it a second command ie to restart a service. So I need to know how to either substitute a space for another character or somehow be able to pass a command ie service apache restart with the first arugment

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was the following:

```
./test.sh echo_var test1;what="service restart apache2";$what
```

This means the spaces are never caught by the script